# Cordova 6 and hyphenated package names

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app  with a package id of `com.test.a-b`

When I upgraded to Cordova 6, I noticed that with this package ID cordova keeps complaining `Error: Error validating package name. Package name must look like: com.company.Name`

The problem is if I remove the hyphen, it is treated as a 'new app' when uploaded to the stores. So how do I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: are you trying to create apk for android too?

Comment: @user1361529 i m using cordova 6.1.0 and tried out similar package name and it works fine. Also as far as i know you are not violating any package naming convention. Hope you are overlooking something,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

thank you for trying. Looks like I over reacted. The issue is with android only -it does not allow hyphens. Looks like in previous versions, it was silently replacing a hyphen with an underscore during compilation. With Cordova 6, it throws an error. So I changed my ionic config.xml to

```
<widget id="com.test.ab" android-packageName="com.test.a_b" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.test.a-b" version="1.1.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

and all is good again

Comment: Thank you for providing your solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot find "android-packageName" anywhere in the docs as a valid attribute for <widget>. If I set it, I still get the error that the package name is invalid.